# Chrome sometimes have half its screen stuck an a certain page

Tags: google-chrome

I have the latest version of chrome, that is, version number: 29.0.1547.57.

Sometimes, the browser gets half its screen stuck on some page, while the upper half changes when I change sites.

For example: the YouTube part on the following image is stuck, when I changed to Google the upper half changed, but the lower half was still suck at YouTube.

Note: The video did not play after I changed the site

What can I do to resolve the problem ?

[image]